# nginx regex redirect if specific string doesn't exist

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, amp-html

Right now I have a line redirecting anything ending in /amp/ to the URL with amp/ removed (since I installed an AMP plugin a while back and then deleted it and am now preventing 404s).

Now I am installing AMP again but want to only have it functioning for pages that have /news/ within them like:

https://www.examplesite.com/news/name-of-article/

so if it has /news/ within the URL, it should allow /amp/ to work and not do a redirect:

https://www.examplesite.com/news/name-of-article/amp/

If it doesn't have /news/ it shouldn't allow /amp/ and should remove /amp/ from the trailing end of the URL.

Right now I have this in my config file to remove /amp/ at all times:

rewrite ^(.*/)amp/$ $1 permanent;

What would be the correct rewrite to make it work the new way and allow /amp/ if /news/ is found within the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion in the regular expression to discard matches that begin with the `/news/` string.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(?!/news/)(.*/)amp/$ $1 permanent;
```

See [this documenmt](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for details.